# How can I iterate over the terms in a taxonomy outside the list.html using Zola?

Tags: rust, template-engine, zola, tera

I've found out you can use

```
{% set posts = get_taxonomy(kind="posts") %}
```

to retrieve a taxonomy but I'm clueless how to iterate over the terms of the taxonomy in for example single.html of this taxonomy.

I tried things like the following, but I get:

> "Tried to iterate using key value on variable 'posts', but it is
>   missing a key"

```
{% set posts = get_taxonomy(kind="posts") %}
{% for term in posts %}
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="{{ term.permalink }}">
      {{ term.name }}
    </a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why did you tag it with the [tag:tera] tag, when you ask about zola?

Comment: @hellow Zola uses Tera, a template engine for Rust and otherwise the post wouldn't have any visibility at all because it's just starting out.

Comment: *"Zola uses Tera"* that combined with that the [tag:zola] is new is okay-ish. But because you use [tag:rust] gives it enough visbility I guess. Leave it for now :)

Answer (score 3):

`get_taxonomy` returns a struct with keys `items` & `kind`.  You can debug using:

```
{% set posts = get_taxonomy(kind="posts") %}

<code>{{ posts.kind | json_encode(pretty=true) }}

{{ posts.items | json_encode(pretty=true) }}</code>
```

`kind` seems to have [`TaxonomyConfig`](https://www.getzola.org/documentation/templates/taxonomies/) structure and each element in `items` seems to have `TaxonomyTerm` structure.